# Is very slight anisocoria (differing size of pupils) and also quite slight ptosis (basically droopy eyelid) problematic?

Tags: cats, eye-disease

I've noticed that my cat's left pupil is tho very slightly but consistently larger than the other one. There's also a slight droopiness of the eyelid on that same eye. Both of these are hardly noticeable, but they are there. The cat is behaving normally and seems to be totally healthy otherwise. It is a young castrated male (about 3-4 years old). Should I be worried?

Comment: it does not sound serious,but the next time you take your cat to the vet you might want to ask the vet about it.it is smart to get the cat examined once a year for vaccsines-deworming and a checkup.if your cat gets problems walking or show problems with the eyesight bring it to the vet right now.

Comment: Good question! I would maybe check with a vet to be sure. However, I have noticed our cat slightly having this. It’s like one eye is more squinty than the other. When he goes to blink one eyelid is more open than the other. After a few hours his eyes are fine. It will switch from eye to eye. I just have suspected maybe he has something in his eye (like a hair). Seems like normal behavior when I would get something in my eye - I can’t open it as much and want to keep it closed. This may not be the same thing you are referencing! Hopefully everything is ok and has gotten better.